# numpy.loadtxt could not convert string to float

Tags: python, csv, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import string


time_1=np.loadtxt('1.csv',delimiter=',',
                  skiprows=0,usecols=(0,),unpack=False)
```

I use numpy.loadtxt to read a CSV file. as showed above. However, it always has

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

the csv file like this

41795.00

41795.00

41795.02

41795.02

41795.03

Comment: It should work. Maybe your file is of different format than posted here, or has some special characters, etc.

Comment: I get the csv file by Excel, I don't know if there is some thing different, and when I input type(time_1[o]), it shows "<type 'numpy.string_'>". I am wondering if some method can change the str to float?

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be you have extra commas at the end of a line. The value error warning usually shows the string that it couldn't convert, but in your case it's a blank, meaning it was trying to convert a blank to a float, which could be the blank after a trailing comma.

The solution might not be within `loadtxt` which is faulty. Try `genfromtxt`.